# Do Asgardians get sick?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel

Being that Asgardians are supposed to be an advanced race similar to humans and this is what a [Wiki-page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asgard_%28comics%29#The_six_races) says about them,

> Although they look human, all Asgardians possess certain superhuman
>   physical attributes. They are extremely long-lived (though not purely
>   immortal like their Olympian counterparts), aging at an extremely slow
>   rate upon reaching adulthood (through the periodic consumption of the
>   golden apples of Idunn). Asgardian flesh and bone is three times
>   denser than similar human tissue, contributing to their superhuman
>   strength and weight. An average Asgardian male can lift 30 tons (27.2
>   metric tons); an average Asgardian female can lift about 25 tons (22.7
>   metric tons). **Asgardians are immune to all terrestrial diseases** and
>   resistant to conventional injury (however this resilience seems
>   relatively incapable of defeating the zombie plague in Earth-2149 that
>   affects even Asgardians). The metabolism of the Asgardians gives them
>   superhuman stamina in all physical activities.[27]

In this scene they use a [Soul Forge](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Soul_Forge),

The Wiki-page states,

> The Soul Forge is an Asgardian medical device that generates quantum
>   fields to highlight the patient's physiology, **making any form of**
>   **internal infection more apparant.**

So , I am a little confused, why have a Soul Forge on Asgard that makes it easier to detect illness (specifically she says ," Its a medical device") when the Wiki page says that the Asgardians are immune to disease. Or, is it used on other beings to help them when they get sick. But that confuses me too, due to the fact that Odin says she doe not belong here and to send her home and have Doctors look at her.

### So my question is, is there any circumstance where Asgardians get sick from illness?

Comment: Maybe they can catch **extraterrestrial** diseases? Your quotation only says they're immune to **terrestrial** diseases.

Comment: Your citation regarding diseases is for the comics version. Do they have a soul forge in the comics? Do you have any citation stating that they can't get a disease in the MCU? This may just be a difference between the continuities.

Comment: @phantom42, I don't really care what its from, but more-so to if this is true.

Comment: Given that a disease is an outside force of some sort impacting or degrading your given physiology from within it is totally possible to an extent. Thor was affected by Wanda's abilities. If that can cause an effect, they are not fully immune to everything, as you already mentioned; then who is to say that something else out there could not do something similar and have the effect of a fever as opposed to hallucinations... just takes the right (or wrong) outside force.

Answer (score 1):

> **Odinsleep** might be an example.

Odin essentially goes into a coma once in a while.  To restore his god-like strength.

So many [shenanigans](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=odinsleep&searchToken=264rdk0bcii1qs3z2jfg08mx4) have been attempted by others during the many Odinsleep episodes that you could consider it a disease or a disability.

Even humans don't have wide agreement about what causes disease.  Native American shamanic traditions believe that illness is the spirit's way of reentering the body. Illness is viewed in magical terms in some cultures.

Arthur C. Clarke said that sufficiently advanced technology would seem like magic to less advanced cultures.

So Odinsleep may be a disease in the shamanic sense. Part of a culture so advanced that it seems magical to those who do not grasp its science.